# How to get Delphi to serialize dynamically created controls along with events attached to them?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a container control which is `TFramedScrollBox`. This in turn contains `TFlowLayout` which in turn contains `TPanel` and `TRectangle` in them.

Again `TPanel` can contain other controls like Edit Box, Combo Box, etc.

So the hierarchy is like this:

```
TFramedScrollBox
   |->TFlowLayout 
         |-> TPanel 
         |     |-> EditBox
         |     |-> ComboBox
         |     |-> DateTime Picker
         |     |-> Label
         |     |-> CheckBox
         |     |-> Radio Buttons
         |     |-> ListBox
         |-> TRectangle
```

Actually all the controls in `TFramedScrollBox` (except for `TRectangle`) are created dynamically at runtime. At time of creation I am attaching events to each control as necessary based on different criteria.

Here is the code that I use to attache events to controls are time of creation:

```
pnlNewRow.OnClick := RowClick;
pnlNewRow.OnMouseEnter := RowMouseEnter;
pnlNewRow.OnMouseLeave := RowMouseLeave;
pnlNewRow.OnDblClick   := RowDblClick;
```

I want to save all the controls in the container control will its sub components & sub-sub components along with events attached to each control in a field in SQLite. And in future load all the components form SQLite and create them on form.

I tried to serialize the container component but only the components are getting serialized and the events attached to it are not getting serialized.

Here is the code snippet that I am using to serialize components:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  TS: TStringStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  MS.WriteComponent(sbMain);
  MS.Position := 0;
  TS := TStringStream.Create;
  ObjectBinaryToText(MS, TS);
  TS.Position := 0;

  ShowMessage(TS.DataString);
end;
```

Please guide as to how I can save all the events a component is linked to and also the custom properties (that I plan to add in future) that are attached to it.

Comment: You should only save the minimal amount of information needed to recreate the UI. Serializing whole objects is a bad approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please compile and run this minimal FMX project

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
  protected
  public
  end;
[...]
function ComponentToString(AComponent : TComponent) : String;
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  Writer : TWriter;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create('');
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Writer := TWriter.Create(MS, 4096);

  try
    Writer.Root := AComponent;
    Writer.WriteSignature;
    Writer.WriteComponent(AComponent);
    Writer.FlushBuffer;
    MS.Position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(MS, SS);
    Result := SS.DataString;
  finally
    Writer.Free;
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := ComponentToString(Form1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

Clicking Button1 writes this to Memo1:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 224
  [...]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  [...]
  object Button1: TButton
    IsPressed = True
    [...]
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    [...]
  end
end
```

which, as you can see, includes the two event handlers of Form1 and the single one
of Button1 and is like what the .DFM would contain.  Isn't that what you were asking for?

And since you can store `ComponentToString` as a library routine, I'm not sure it is correct to say "to serialize events you need to manually write code", well, not form-specific code anyway.

Btw, this works fine with dynamically created controls.  Add a TButton, called Button, in the Private, Protected or Public section of the form and the following code to the FormCreate handler

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button :=  TButton.Create(Self);
  Button.Name := 'Button';
  Button.Parent := Self;
  Button.OnClick := Button1Click;
end;
```

Clicking either button produces a similar list as the one above, but with the addition of the extra, dynamically created, button.

Comment: So, has this answered your q?

Answer (score 0):

To serialize events you need to manually write code. I don't see any other way.

Comment: Can you assist by providing a small sample as to what kind of code I should write. Currently I am saving the extra property settings and events information in another file but this tends to get out of sync over a period of time.

Comment: It looks like there is an error in your code. `ObjectBinaryToText` is called before `TS: = TStringStream.Create`.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. It is copy-n-paste error. Will correct it immediately.

Comment: Also I was wrong about the question. MartynA showed a good example. Using `TWriter`, you can solve your issue.